# Custom button template rendering issue

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a custom button template in my application and I am having an issue related to its border rendering.

Here is the simplified version of this template:

```
<Style x:Key="AcceptButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Style.Setters>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF1C625B"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#FF1C625B"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
        <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="Template" Value="{DynamicResource ButtonTemplate}"/>
        <Setter Property="UseLayoutRounding" Value="True"/>

        <Setter Property="ap:IconProperties.SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="ap:IconProperties.UseLayoutRounding" Value="True"/>
    </Style.Setters>
    <Style.Resources>
        <ControlTemplate x:Key="ButtonTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
            <Grid>
                <Border x:Name="Root"
                        Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                        CornerRadius="4"
                        SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"
                        UseLayoutRounding="{TemplateBinding UseLayoutRounding}">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"
                                HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                                Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                                VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}">
                        <Viewbox Height="{Binding Path=(ap:IconProperties.Height), RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}"
                                 Margin="{Binding Path=(ap:IconProperties.Margin), RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}"
                                 SnapsToDevicePixels="{Binding Path=(ap:IconProperties.SnapsToDevicePixels), RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}"
                                 Stretch="Uniform"
                                 Width="{Binding Path=(ap:IconProperties.Width), RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}"
                                 UseLayoutRounding="{Binding Path=(ap:IconProperties.UseLayoutRounding), RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}">
                            <Path x:Name="Icon"
                                  Data="{Binding Path=(ap:IconProperties.Data), RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}"
                                  Fill="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"/>
                        </Viewbox>

                        <TextBlock x:Name="TextContent"
                                   Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"
                                   Text="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                                   VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                   FontSize="14"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Border>
            </Grid>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Style.Resources>
</Style>
```

This style is giving me a really nice button appearance, especially with the animations which were removed in the example for brevity. But one small issue is not letting me mark this style as complete.

Here is how the button looks like:

[image]

But if we will look closer - we will notice some weird "holes" in the layout:

[image]

A bit closer one more time:

[image]

I was expecting this part to look like the following:

[image]

Could you please tell me - is there any way to fix this? I know I can add some extra layers to achieve my goal, but I would like to have this fixed in a proper way.

Thanks.

### **EDIT**

The first thing you might have on your mind is - why doesn't he just set the border thickness to 0? Well, the short answer - it is required for the animations.

Comment: did you use inspector to find wich element draw these borders?

Comment: Set BorderThickness to 0 when Background and BorderBrush are identical.

Comment: @EhsanVali, of course, it is the border named "Root". There are not too many components in the template, I tried to keep it as simple as possible :)

Comment: @Clemens, sorry, had to mention that in my question. I have to have the border thickness set to 1. It is required for the animations.

Comment: You may draw an unfilled Border on top of the one with the Background.

Comment: @Clemens, certainly will do so, if there is no other way. I will wait, maybe somebody else knows the better way, it might be just some rendering regulation property on the border element itself.

Comment: try to set Borderthikness = 0, if the white border removed, then set borderthikness = 1 on its animation, where its needed

Comment: @EhsanVali, I did that before posting a question but changing the border thickness creates a slight resize effect which I need to avoid.

Comment: How about the inner border as transparent color, so the green background should come through.

Comment: @DRapp, yeah, looks like something like that is the only way for me... These damn extra layers... Hoped to avoid that :)